# Multilevel bootstrap dropdown from recursive function

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, recursion, nopcommerce

**Problem:**

I'm working on a nopCommerce theme and I'm incorporating Bootstrap.  Because nopCommerce allows an indefinite number of Parent categories, I need the theme to be able to handle as many sub-dropdown-menu items as the user may add.

What is happening now is when the first-level dropdown item is clicked, any other sub-category with children is also being "dropped down".

My helper function is as follows:

```
@helper RenderMenuLine(CategorySimpleModel category, int level)
{

    bool isDrop = (category.SubCategories.Count > 0);
    string toggleName = "dropdown" + level.ToString();
    if (isDrop)
    {
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = category.SeName })" class="dropdown-toggle" data-target="@toggleName" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                @category.Name
                <span class="caret"></span> 
                @if (category.NumberOfProducts.HasValue)
                {       
                    <text></text> @T("Categories.TotalProducts", category.NumberOfProducts.Value)
                }
            </a>

            @{ var subCats = category.SubCategories.Where(x => x.IncludeInTopMenu); }
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="@toggleName">
                @foreach (var subCat in subCats)
                {
                    @RenderMenuLine(subCat, level++)
                }
            </ul>

        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = category.SeName })">@category.Name</a></li>
    }
}
```

and my markup for the base menu is as follows:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.RouteUrl("HomePage")"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            @{
                var categories = Model.Categories.Where(x => x.IncludeInTopMenu).ToList();

            }
            @foreach (var item in categories)
            {
                @RenderMenuLine(item, 0)
            }
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

I've looked at other samples of Bootstrap multi-level dropdown menus -- however from what I've seen, the markup my helper-function builds should be working.  Here's a picture of what it looks like when I hover over the parent category: : "Computers" (POS is a subcategory of Software):

[image: When hovering over top-level parent]

**Note** I know additional styling will probably be necessary.  Right now I'm only concerned with functionality.  Also, the level integer and togglename string exist because I thought maybe I needed a way to tie the dropdown toggle to the menu itself.

Answer (score 0):

**I would still very much like a bootstrap-specific solution, but with a little editing and CSS, I did get the results I was looking for:**

I was able to do this by adjusting my helper function just a little bit, and adding some CSS styling to do the rest.

I added a CSS class called "dropdown-submenu", and this class will be used for a "dropdown in a dropdown", and adjusted my helper function to keep track of where we were using the level int in the function signature:

```
@helper RenderMenuLine(CategorySimpleModel category, int level)
{

bool isDrop = (category.SubCategories.Count > 0);
string dropDownClass;           // The class we assign to the dropdown markup depends on where we are
if (level > 0)                  // If we are already in a dropdown menu
{
    dropDownClass = "dropdown-submenu";
}
else    // otherwise we are in the root menu, or level = 0
{
    dropDownClass = "dropdown";
}
if (isDrop)
{
    <li class="@dropDownClass"> 
        <a tabindex="-1" href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = category.SeName })" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            @category.Name
            @if (level == 0)
            { <span class="caret"></span> }
            @if (category.NumberOfProducts.HasValue)
            {
                <text></text> @T("Categories.TotalProducts", category.NumberOfProducts.Value)
            }
        </a>

        @{ var subCats = category.SubCategories.Where(x => x.IncludeInTopMenu); }
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach (var subCat in subCats)
            {
                @RenderMenuLine(subCat, level++)
            }
        </ul>

    </li>
}
else
{
    <li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Category", new { SeName = category.SeName })">@category.Name</a></li>
}
}
```

And my CSS for this new dropdown is:

```
li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu {

    position:relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {

    top:0;
    left:100%;
    margin-top:-6px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
    display: none;
}
li.dropdown-submenu:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    float:right;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color:#cccccc;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

[image: Pic of mouseover dropdown]